# Automapper customTypeConverter

Tags: c#, automapper

In AutoMappingProfiles I have such a map

```
 CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options =>
            {
               ...
            })
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Points, options =>
            {
               ...
            })
```

Both `Order` and `OrderDto` has same properties with same types and name except few of them which have complex types, therefore I used `.ForMember` in order to handle them.

Now I want to move this mapping logic into separate converter class and then in mapper I can just replace it like this

`CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>().ConvertUsing(new OrderModelTypeConverter());`

I want to do this because I need to use same mapping into different project within same solution.

I started to write a converter:

```
public class OrderModelTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<OrderEntity, Order>
{
    public OrderDto Convert(Order order, OrderDto orderDto, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        ///how to access to CreateMap ??
      
          .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options =>
            {
               ...
            })
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Points, options =>
            {
               ...
            })
        return result;
    }
}
```

How to access to CreateMap inside converter ?
I want to use same logic where automapper maps properties with same types and names automatically and for special ones I will simply use `.ForMember` but I cannot find way how to do this in converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to do this because I need to use same mapping into different project within same solution.

Not a direct answer but arguably the easier approach would be to move the configuration to some extension method:

```
public static class ExprExt
{
    public static IMappingExpression<Order, OrderDto> ConfigureOrderModelTypeMapping(this IMapperConfigurationExpression e) => e.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
        .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => { })
        .ForMember(destination => destination.Points, options => { });
}

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(e =>
{
    e.ConfigureOrderModelTypeMapping();
});
```

Or even better - use the build-in approach for modular configuration [with `Profile`'s](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances):

```
public class OrderModelProfile : Profile
{
    public OrderModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => { })
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Points, options => { });
    }
}

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(e =>
{
    e.AddProfile<OrderModelProfile>(); // or use assembly scanning
});
```

Comment: Solution with Profile works fine for me and solves the issue, thank you !

P.S. Nevertheless It is interesting to see solution with CustomTypeConverter as well

Comment: @dave101ua was glad to help! As for the custom converter - I'm afraid it is not correct abstraction here since it supposed to.prpvida a completely custom mapping, so no `CreateMap` there (unless you are willing to create a separate inner mapper). If answer works for you feel free to upvote and mark it as accepted one ;)